# How to correctly use smart pointers in OOP

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I am wondering what is the correct way to use `std::unique_ptr` in an Object-Oriented Programming. Let's say I have a class that contains an member object that can be passed by pointer

```cpp
class B
{/*Some code here*/};

class A
{
public:
    A();
    B* getMember();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> member
};
```

First: Should the member be a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` to avoid memory leaks?

Second, what would be the implementation of my getter if in cases where I want to

1. Allow modification of the member?
2. Not allow modification of the member?

I initially did:

```cpp
B* A::getMember()
{
    return member.get();
}
```

But I am considering to have the member be a `std::shared_ptr` and adapt the getter:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A();
    std::shared_ptr getMember();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> member
};

std::shared_ptr A::getMember()
{
    return member;
}
```

What is the standard and most-widely accepted implementation?

Comment: Tip: In C++ there's no point in mentioning "Object Oriented Programming". It's understood that's one of the things you are probably doing. This isn't the 1970s where "OOP" was some newfangled thing that needed to be explained, so there's no need to draw attention to that fact. Perhaps what you're really talking about here is the concept of *encapsulation*, which is a very specific aspect of "OOP".

Comment: It very much depends, how you get the pointer, whether the pointed to class may be copied (for semantical or size = performance reasons), who owns (=destructs) the pointer, if the pointer can be different classes (inheritance). You can typically store as `optional<B>`, as `B`, as `B&`, as `B*`, as `unique_ptr<B>` and as `shared_ptr<B>` or `weak_ptr<B>` and all make sense for specific use cases. You can return the member as any of those with even some of the combinations making sense.

Comment: What do you mean by modification of the member? Store another pointer? Or modify the existing pointed to object? Where does this object come from? Who/what allocates it in memory? Is it used elsewhere? How long does the B object live compared to the A object.

Comment: If the class owns the B object: Often storing an owning `unique_ptr` is combined with a getter to the non-owning raw pointer, whereas the setter would receive an owning `unique_ptr` to replace the old member. If the class does not own the B object: Just store a raw pointer. `shared_ptr` are only used, if the ownership over the B object is shared, and it is unclear, which A object with the same B pointer is destructed last. And if the B object cannot be owned by an object outliving all A. Sometimes a sign for murky software architecture, `shared_ptr` should not be the default solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shared_ptr` implies a complex ownership rule where the object in question is owned by multiple co-equal parties, and its lifetime cannot be determined easily.  Deciding to go with `shared_ptr` because it is simpler or easier is like using a bazooka to kill a fruit fly bothering you because it is more powerful than a fly swatter.

In C++ there is no simple way to avoid thinking about ownership.

`unique_ptr` provides a simple owned-by relationship to manage lifetimes.  Value types (or types with value semantics) provide even simpler lifetime management.  Nobody gets confused by the lifetime of `int x=7;` past a novice.

C++ can support runtime polymorphic value types; see `std::function`.  When in doubt use values.

```
class A {
public:
  A();
  B b;
};
```

far easier to think about.

Now, if you are doing something like a UI framework, then your UI elements are going to be owned by your framework.  You'll probably want a naming system, configuration files in an ASL, and a way to connect your UI to actions and modify your UI with code.

Next to none of this will involve a class with a member subobject returning pointers to it via accessors.

Maybe your UI is immutable copy on write shared ptr data attached to names you can get/setfrom the framework.  Here the immutable data is truely shared; it acts like an integer.

Regardless, you have to think about what it means for a B to exist seperate from an A whenever you share a B pointer, be it dumb, unique, shared, immutable or copy on write.  Either B becomes some interface to some part of A's state, in which case its lifetime is logically tied, or it lives independently, in which case you probably want value semantics.

And having made that decision, a shared ptr is probably the wrong lifetime rule.  If it is an interface to part of A's state, it outliving A as implied by shared ownership is an error, and if it is a value you set/get, getting it and modifying the state implicitly acts as an interface to A's state!  Sithout A even knowing!

A being deliver ed state change notifications from a B?  Bring able to get the B that provides state change notifications?  Sensible; here, B could be UI theming colour, and A a control.  But here A probably has a shared ptr to a const theme color set plus a subscription token to theme change messages.  (here the colour set is legitimately shared)

In short, defaulting to shared ptr is bad.  Use unique ptr when you cannot use values.  Ownership follows lifetime, which follows from semantics.  Default to values, C++ is one of the few OO languages that has really solid value support.